# Scala - How to set default value instead None for Option[Int]

Tags: scala, functional-programming

I want to extend class `Option[Int]` it so that it returns `0` if `None` and value in `Some` if it's not `None`. How should I make the below code  work?

```
Some(10).default // returns 10
Option.empty[Int].default // returns 0
```

Comment: Maybe you're just looking for this?: `None.getOrElse(0)`?

Comment: @XavierGuihot I think in real code it will be most right decision, but for my task i must exactly extend Option[Int] (make code from my question workable).

Comment: Will be difficult as it's [sealed](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.2/scala/Option.html). One dirty solution would be to wrap an Option inside a class, redefining methods (get, ...) to call the wrapped option methods and including the `default` method.

Comment: @XavierGuihot thanks, i will be look in this direction.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can define an implicit class with the method you want, that wraps an `Option[Int]`:

```
implicit class OptionIntExtension(option: Option[Int]) {
  def default: Int = option.getOrElse(0)
}
```

When this class is imported into scope, the code from your question works.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this a couple of ways.

With pattern matching:

```
val input: Option[Int] = Some(10)

input match {
  case Some(value) => 10
  case None => 0
}
```

Output:

```
res0: Int = 10
```

---

With `getOrElse`:

```
val input: Option[Int] = Some(10)
input.getOrElse(0)
```

Output:

```
res1: Int = 10
```

---

**EDIT**

To make this work like in your original question, pop it into an implicit class in scope (as Kolmar suggests):

```
implicit class DefaultExtension(input: Option[Int]) {
  def default: Int = input.getOrElse(0)
}

Some(10).default
res0: Int = 10

Option.empty[Int].default
res1: Int = 0
```

---

```
implicit class DefaultExtension(input: Option[Int]) {
  def default: Int = input match {
    case Some(value) => 10
    case None => 0
  }
}

Some(10).default
res0: Int = 10

Option.empty[Int].default
res1: Int = 0
```

Comment: I need make code from my question workable, this decision works if take it in implicit class, thanks.

Comment: I amended my answers to incorporate Kolmar's suggestion. Hope this helps!